# How to access menu button onLongClick in Android?

Tags: android, menu, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

How can I set a listener for long-click performed on hardware Menu button? What is the way of programmatic access to the Menu button?

Moreover how can I distinguish long-click from single-click? (As far as I know when long-click is performed the single-click event is propagated as well - I do not want this to happen because I need 2 different actions for these 2 situations. Long-click and single-click separate listeners for the device Menu button)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shoule be fairly straight forward.  Check out the [KeyEvent.Callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html) on the Android developer's website.

There you will find `onKeyLongPress()` as well as `onKeyDown()` and `onKeyUp()`.  This should get you on the right track.  Comment or post you code if you need any further help.

Edit:  I just re-read the question.  If you are having trouble distinguishing single click from long click, you will need to use `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` and check the duration of the click.  Esentially you will start a timer in the `onKeyDown` and check the time in the `onKeyUp`.  You will have to watch for `FLAG_CANCELED`.

Further Edit:  I found the time to do a couple of tests.  This code should do what you want (`onKeyUp()` gets only short press events and `onLongPress()` gets only long press events).

The key thing here is in the call to `event.startTracking()` in the `onKeyDown()` handler.

Place in `Activity` (this should also work in a custom view as well but untested):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        // Handle Long Press here
        Log.i("KeyCheck", "LongPress");
        return true;    
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
@Override   
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("KeyCheck", "KeyDown" + keyCode);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        event.startTracking(); //call startTracking() to get LongPress event
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && event.isTracking()
            && !event.isCanceled()) {
        // handle regular key press here
        Log.i("KeyCheck", "KeyUp");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: this works just beautifully, tracking really helps here. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. I want holding Menu key doesn't show soft keyboard. Your solution even disable my menu options.

Comment: I agree works great if you don't want Menu to work at all, completely disables single press menu.  Is there a way to make this work when you don't want to ignore single press?