# android: Activity starts 2 times with OnTouchListener()

Tags: android

I've a motion class for a longer pressed_state button. It works really fine!

But does anybody knows why in this code block my activity is starting 2 times? When i'm pressing the back button, i've to do this 2 times.

Thx for any help!

---

**This is my java code:**

```
   Button MenuBtnStart;  

   final Handler handlerBtnStart = new Handler();

          MenuBtnStart.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
          public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {

          MenuBtnStart.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hover));

                 v.setPressed(true);

                 handlerBtnStart.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                           public void run() {

                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(TextActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                            TextActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

                        v.setPressed(false);

                    }

                }, 900);  // end of Handler new Runnable()

                 return true;
          } 

 });  // end of OnTouchListener()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only be activating it if the action is [`DOWN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN); there may be a [`MOVE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_MOVE) or [`UP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP) action after this, which would activate it a second time.

```
final Handler handlerBtnStart = new Handler();

MenuBtnStart.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { 
            MenuBtnStart.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hover));

            v.setPressed(true);

            handlerBtnStart.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                    ThisActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

                    v.setPressed(false);

                }

            }, 900);  // end of Handler new Runnable()

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

});  // end of OnTouchListener()
```

Comment: I get now an uncaught exception error, whats wrong else? thx a lot 4 help!

Comment: Can you put the full LogCat on pastebin and link it here?

Comment: That error is not as a result of this code. You should close this question (by accepting an answer), and start a new thread with the code from `at.oneclickahead.WorldQuizzer.GameActivity` as well as those logs.

Comment: Mistake was, that the ACTION paramater was set as DOWN, but it should be set to UP, than it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is being called on both `onKeyUp()` and `onKeyDown()` - and these are the methods you should override, not `onTouch()`.

**EDIT:**

I didn't read carefully enough - you're after long clicks, I didn't get it at first. I once received a great answer to similar question. Take a look: [How to access menu button on long click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867033/how-to-access-menu-button-onlongclick-in-android).

Comment: No this is not correct. It's a normal onTouch Situation, with a motion class for a longer state, but not press (click)

Answer (score 0):

You hould handle the ACTION_DOWN event.

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

// Do Something
}
return true;
```